# Get the list of user SIM cards in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sim-card

I have tried different packages, but none of them provided access to the list of SIM card numbers.
(in android 13)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.